# DragonFireSDK and iPhone development on Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, web

So in previous questions about iPhone development on Windows, the basic/easy answer has been "just get a mac."  However, I noticed a comment that mentioned DragonFireSDK. But no one else said anything about it?

Has anyone tried this?  It look pretty legit to me, but I'm new to the iPhone world. I just find it weird that no one has discussed this yet.  I mean, it looks like the perfect tools for the Windows users.

Thanks!

Oh yeah....here's the link to DragonFireSDK: [DragonFireSDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm)

EDIT: This app is for my website, [We, the Pixels](http://wethepixels.com). Any comments on if Dragonfire would be a good fit for an iPhone version of my website?  Thanks!

Comment: Officially, Apple will not approve apps created with this SDK, or any other SDK than the official one. But that's only relevant if you care about submitting to the App Store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DragonFireSDK is good, I have been developing several apps with it, the first of which is now available, a game called Firefox Fun: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-fun/id393933733?mt=8

Comment: Are you reliant on DragonFireSDK's website always being available to submit your application, or if they were just "gone" someday, would you still be able to compile and update your app in the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use DFSDK and got my apps published to apples appstore using the sdk. they have good API it lets you use c/c++ to create your app.