# Can I trust DragonFireSDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Watching their video and browsing their site, it looks like I have to do some kind of mouse olympics to publish an app. I want to publish an app to the App Store for as little money as possible, without using "hacks". Is there any way to do this, and does Apple allow it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DragonFireSDK and iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668175/dragonfiresdk-and-iphone-development-on-windows)

Comment: Whether or not you can trust someone is beyond the scope of this site, but the linked question has responses that describe how the SDK works, including an answer from the developers.  Note that anything that doesn't involve Xcode and a Mac running Snow Leopard would be considered a "hack" for developing iOS applications.

Comment: Guys, he/she didn't need to be downvoted for this question.

Comment: @Alan - The downvote may have been spillover from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753964/how-would-i-build-an-iphone-app-on-windows-closed , which really shouldn't affect the merits of this question.

Comment: @Brad Larson : It appears that the providers of that toolchain seem to say that they do involve Xcode on a remote Mac for the final iOS distribution build.  Seems like they would have to have the developers private keys, certificates, and team leader login though.  So trust is an interesting question.

Comment: @hotpaw2 - True, I saw that, but trust is something that I'm not sure we can objectively address.

Comment: @Brad Larson: I trust your word on that. (Am I doing this right?)

Answer (score 3):

They seem to have posted the names of several apps using their SDK, and apps in the App store are required to include developer contact info.  Write a few of the developers of recent apps using their toolchain, and see if any of their replies give you enough confidence.