# Native development on a Mac vs Dragonfire SDK on Windows - iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, c++, c

I'm wondering what are the main differences between developing for iPhone on a Mac, using the official tools/IDE (Whatever they may be) on a Mac, vs using the Dragonfire SDK on a Windows machine?

Is there a lot more hassle involved going down the Dragonfire route?

My main concern here is cost, I don't own a Mac, and don't really need a new machine right now. So the Dragonfire SDK looks like a cheap alternative to be able to develop right on my Windows machine.

Are there any pitfalls to using the DF SDK, does it present any problems, and will it be easy to transitioning to developing on a Mac in the future if I wanted to?

Also, as the case may be, does the Dragonfire SDK simplify any of the process, as well as being the cheaper option?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, I do NOT intend to develop any games, is Dragonfire SDK suitable for non-game development? Or is it too limited to much outside of games.

As I understand you write the code in C++ for example, then it calls the native Objective-C functions when they build it through their Build Centre feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DragonFireSDK and iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668175/dragonfiresdk-and-iphone-development-on-windows)

Comment: How many applications that I use every day or respect the design of were written using the Dragonfire SDK? 0. If you're unwilling to learn the native conventions of the platform you're targeting, what are the odds that you'll develop something that presents a good user experience?

Comment: It's not that i'm unwilling to learn the native conventions in the slightest, in fact it's quite the opposite. Simply trying to find out how different the two approaches are. I don't code in C++ regularly, so being able to do that doesn't attract me in the slightest to DF SDK. I'd rather learn Objective-C and the native way of creating apps for iOS. Buying a Mac especially for this isn't the most convenient thing - but i'm considering a Mac Mini for it. I really do appreciate your input, I just feel you misunderstood my intentions. I don't own any Apple hardware so I was investigating options.

Comment: Sorry if that came across as a little harsh, it's just that I see a lot of people only wanting to put in the minimal amount of effort because they want to cash in on the iOS gold rush, and the results are usually not pretty.  I've even seen people write applications and submit them to the App Store without ever owning or having used an iOS device, and it shows.  A Mac Mini is a perfectly serviceable iOS development machine, and you can get good deals on refurbs at [Apple's site](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/mac?mco=OTY2ODY3Nw).

Comment: I think you'll find that working in the native development environment will make it much easier to get up to speed, and you'll have the advantages of native debugging, testing, and profiling tools that a cross-platform environment lacks.  It will also be easier to find tutorials and other resources.  Consider it an investment in the platform, which will be paid back quickly if you produce an application that's even slightly successful.  I know many people that reluctantly purchased a Mac for iOS development, and I don't think any of them have regretted it in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragonfire offers an API's using C/C++ , while developping on Mac you'll use Objective-C

To create your executable with DF SDK you have to hand your source code to them so they can build your application on their servers, while for Mac you hand them only your final executable (they provide you all the tools to make your app in your own machine)

Comment: Does handing them your source code have any implications that you know of? That is..There is appropriate protection in place? Also wondering how long it takes for the app to be built. Their website doesn't have that much information really so looking to anybody who has had experience with it. Also couldn't find a trial of any kind.